# Rx2AndroidNetworking that created by amitshekhar not work with android version 31 and above

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java2

**I get this error message when making a request by Rx2AndroidNetworking.**

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.gomini.gominipassenger: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

**This my code**

```
public static Observable<AppVersion> checkAppVersion() {
    return Rx2AndroidNetworking.post(Constant.Api.Url.BASE_URL + Constant.Api.Url.CHECK_APP_VERSION)
            .addBodyParameter(Constant.Api.CheckAppVersion.APP_VERSION, String.valueOf(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE))
            .addBodyParameter(Constant.Api.CheckAppVersion.DEVICE_TYPE, Constant.DEVICE_TYPE)
            .setOkHttpClient(client)
            .build()
            .getObjectObservable(AppVersion.class)
            .compose(RxUtils.applyNetworkSchedulers());
```

**This is used library**

```
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:rx2-android-networking:1.0.2'
```

Comment: WHen you're using a random library off github that hasn't had a release in 5 years, this is what you get.  I suggest not using this library, it appears completely abandoned.  Use something with far more support in the field, like Retrofit or even Volley.

Comment: I agree with you but this legacy project i should fix it and change library with retrofit will be a very high cost.

Comment: It may be worth that cost anyway.  The alternative is to fork this library and fix it yourself.  That also has a cost, and if another issue pops up in the future it will have that cost again.  I'd also worry about it's dependencies-  is it using an outdated version of OkHTTP (what it uses to make the actual calls)?  If so, you're going to have any security bug found since that version.  Networking libraries are the last thing you want to let go obsolete.